# JQuery(document).ready not evalauting on page, but does when in a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, single-page-application

I have a strange issue.  Strange I suppose only in the sense that I have no intuition about the underlying mechanism, and I tried everything I could in the Chrome Developer Tools debugger.  Here is the code snippet that works when I execute it from a file on my desktop by opening in

```
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function () {
            Slider.initModule(jQuery('#slider'));
        }
    );
```

I'm importing jQuery as usual:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the complete page, I am stumped, this should just be a simple example of a chat slider  that I got from "Single Page Web Applications" on Manning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Slider</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #777;
    }
    #slider {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 8px;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 0 8px;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .slider {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 2px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
        background-color: #f00;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Slider = (function () {
        var configMap = {
            extendedHeight: 434,
            extendedTitle: 'Click to retract',
            retractedHeight: 16,
            retractedTitle: 'Click to expand',
            templateHtml: '<div class="slider"></div>'
        }, $slider, toggleSlider, onClickSlider, initModule;
        toggleSlider = function () {
            var sliderHeight = $slider.height();
            if(sliderHeight === configMap.retractedHeight) {
                $slider.animate({height: configMap.extendedHeight})
                        .attr('title', configMap.extendedTitle);
                return true;
            } else if(sliderHeight === configMap.extendedHeight) {
                $slider.animate({height: configMap.retractedHeight})
                        .attr('title', configMap.retractedTitle);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        onClickSlider = function (event) {
            toggleSlider();
            return false;
        };
        initModule = function ($container) {
            $container.html(configMap.templateHtml);
            $slider = $container.find('.slider');
            $slider.attr('title', configMap.retractedTitle)
                    .click(onClickSlider);
            return true;
        };
        return {initModule: initModule};
    })(jQuery);
    jQuery(document).ready(
            function () {
                Slider.initModule(jQuery('#slider'));
            }
    );
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can it be the slider works when the above html is served to Chrome as a file:/// uri, but not when served over a server on localhost, how can this be?

---

Here is an interesting update.

I added an alert to the toggleSlider function, and the pixels were different than the css!

```
alert("HERE! " + sliderHeight);
```

I got 15, but when I save the source and open the file, I get 16!  Whoa!  Whats going on there?  thats why the slider is not opening for me over localhost.

Comment: It looks valid to me, i see no reason for it to work locally and not on a webserver.

Comment: view the source to make sure the same code is running, see the console for errors/warnings and finally put some logging calls inside your scripts to check if they get executed..

Comment: What @GabyakaG.Petrioli said. Runs fine locally under a server. Are you absolutely sure you're not getting a cached copy?

Comment: Why are you using the height to decide whether to open or close and not use just a flag ? (*or even a class that you toggle on the slider ?*)

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be working for me, check the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zw3B/).

Unless the below code is meant to open the slider on load?

```
jQuery(document).ready(
        function () {
            Slider.initModule(jQuery('#slider'));
        }
);
```

Also note that JQuery will not work locally if your PCs date and time are wrong.

Comment: Hi Jamie, it's odd, it looks like that function fires when loaded from a local file, but not my server.  I wonder what Im missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another script just for the loading like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Slider = (function () {
    var configMap = {
        extendedHeight: 434,
        extendedTitle: 'Click to retract',
        retractedHeight: 16,
        retractedTitle: 'Click to expand',
        templateHtml: '<div class="slider"></div>'
    }, $slider, toggleSlider, onClickSlider, initModule;
    toggleSlider = function () {
        var sliderHeight = $slider.height();
        if(sliderHeight === configMap.retractedHeight) {
            $slider.animate({height: configMap.extendedHeight})
                    .attr('title', configMap.extendedTitle);
            return true;
        } else if(sliderHeight === configMap.extendedHeight) {
            $slider.animate({height: configMap.retractedHeight})
                    .attr('title', configMap.retractedTitle);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    onClickSlider = function (event) {
        toggleSlider();
        return false;
    };
    initModule = function ($container) {
        $container.html(configMap.templateHtml);
        $slider = $container.find('.slider');
        $slider.attr('title', configMap.retractedTitle)
                .click(onClickSlider);
        return true;
    };
    return {initModule: initModule};
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Then create another one with this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(
        function () {
            Slider.initModule(jQuery('#slider'));
        }
);
</script>
```

For some reason I have experienced sometimes when I finish making a script and call it on the same one, it won't work. But when I call it on a separate script, it does magically work.

Comment: Thanks Yisera, I got excited about this answer, especially with magic involved. However, I got the same result: I could move the slider when the file was loaded from my desktop, but not the server.  Still stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you change the version of jquery to be 1.9 ?

Comment: Hi Romel, nope, still the same.  I tried 1.10.2 but the effect is the same, the slider doesn't open when served over localhost, but does in a file.